# I want to know how to on click in navigation bar it will make the scroll and take it to that specific secition

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router

I'm using **React** with JavaScript for making a personal portfolio website.

I wanted to know **how to implement that when there is an interaction with the navigation bar it will scroll down to that specific section** in that page only not a new page. This is the navbar code that.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import "./Navbar.css"
import { FaBars, FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa'

const Navbar = () => {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false)
  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click)
  const [color, setColor] = useState(false)
  const changeColor = () => {
    if (window.scrollY >= 100) {
      setColor(true);
    }
    else {
      setColor(false);
    }   
  };
  window.addEventListener('scroll', changeColor);
    
  return (
    <div className={color ? "header header-bg":"header"}>
      <Link to='/Home'>
        <h1 className="header6">Portfolio</h1>
      </Link>
      <ul className={click?"nav-menu.active":"nav-menu"}>
        <li><Link to="header">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="#projects">Projects</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='#qualification'>Qualification</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='experience'>Experience</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='#about'>About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="#contact">Contact</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <div className='hamburger' onClick={handleClick}>
      {click
        ? (<FaTimes size={20} style={{ color: "whitesmoke" }} />)
        : (<FaBars size={20} style={{ color: "whitesmoke" }} />)
      }
    </div>
  </div>
)}

export default Navbar
```

I tried using react `Link` and html id concepts as well but it was no use.

Comment: The `react-router-dom` `Link` component is for linking to *other* "pages". Where are the elements you are wanting to link to being rendered? Please [edit] to provide a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I think you should prefix the URL with `"/home"`. So, it becomes from `"#about"` to `"/home#about"` or add `"/"` like `"/#about"` if it is on the same page.
over all URL must start with `"/"`.